# Giving error in mysql Insert Query When I am insert any data but i have only name and email at start level

Tags: sql-insert, mysql-error-1292

When I am insert any data but i have only name and email at start level

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3,"text","xyz@gmail.com","","","","","")
```

But getting error like this

> #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'email_verified_at' at row 1

Comment: datetime should not be empty .....

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `users` table?

Comment: plz post the laravel insert code...

Answer (score 0):

enter correct value for the field `email_verified_at` which empty in the query.

Answer (score 0):

set the type of `email_verified_at` to `timestamp` and choose the default value to `current_timestamp` and then you can leave blank that field in your query, and it is better I think.